# Insert text into Word Document that is editable only by a plugin

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to determine if it is possible to create a Word Plugin that inserts text into a document that cannot be edited or removed by a user. I do not want to use a macro.

**Example...**

*1) "MyPlugin" inserts "ABCDEF" into a document. I cannot change or delete that text inside the document. I can only change or delete that text using "MyPlugin".*

*2) I send this document to my buddy who does not have "MyPlugin" sees "ABCDEF" but cannot change or delete it at all because he does not have "MyPlugin".*

**Caveat...**

This string does not have to be literally uneditable. It just needs to be locked in such a way that the average user editing the document cannot alter or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using the *Restrict Editing* options?

[image]

You should be able to do this by selecting all of the document *except* the portions that you don't want users to be able to edit, and control that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Protect` method:

```
this.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, 
    ref noReset, ref password, ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178793.aspx